# How to "route" text from Zoom chat into another application (like Max/MSP). (self.learnprogramming)

Tags: chat, puredata, max-msp-jitter

I was trying to do the following:

I needed a script that would be "reading" the chat of the current Zoom meeting, and routing that text into another application (in specific, Max/MSP).

I am trying to have live interaction between the participants in the call and th Max/MSP patch. I know what I need to do on Max side to "interpret" the text, but I am clueles on how I could "route" the text from the Zoom chat.

I have little experience in other programming languages, but am open to learn from other scripts.

Sorry if I'm being a little vague. I searched for similar questions and didn't find anything like what I need.

Comment: On StackOverflow, we expect specific programming questions, we are not a code-writing service, and, as you have correctly pointed out, you are being a little too vague. The problem is that this question would probably be answered with different opinions, so there is not a correct answer. And, just to help you out with the problem: in such cases arguably the best solution is to find an appropriate (zoom) api (application programming interface), and if that doesn't help you (e.g. there is no api), I'd recommend using selenium (browser controller) to dynamically read the meeting html.

Answer (score 1):

You would typically access the Zoom API and query a user's chat messages:

https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/zoom-api/chat-messages/getchatmessages

This should be possible to do in Max, using the maxurl object:

https://docs.cycling74.com/max8/refpages/maxurl